# How change profile image of app's?

Tags: facebook

Now, my app's profile image (https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/picture)
is
redirected default facebook image(https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y6/r/_xS7LcbxKS4.gif).

how do I change the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the App settings Dashboard:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Goto Settings -> Auth Dialog and you should be able to edit the app logo.

Comment: i am changed app logo... but still https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/picture goto facebook default image (https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/y6/r/_xS7LcbxKS4.gif)... T.T